# Upload Images in two different paths Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'll try to upload an Images into two different path, but it always uploaded in single path only, here's my code in a model :

```
public function save()
{
    $post = $this->input->post();
    $this->product_id = uniqid();
    $this->name = $post["name"];
    $this->price_awal = $post["price_awal"];
    $this->price = $post["price"];
    $this->image = $this->_uploadImage();
    $this->image2 = $this->_uploadImage2('./upload/');
    $this->jenis_produk = $post["jenis_produk"];
    $this->warna = $post["warna"];
    $this->description = $post["description"];
    $this->db->insert($this->_table, $this);
}
```

The upload function (also in the model)

```
private function _uploadImage()
{
    $config['upload_path']          = './upload/product/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['file_name']            = $this->product_id;
    $config['overwrite']            = true;
    $config['max_size']             = 1024; // 1MB
    // $config['max_width']            = 1024;
    // $config['max_height']           = 768;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ($this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
        return $this->upload->data("file_name");
    }
    
    return "default.jpg";
}

private function _uploadImage2($path)
{
$config['upload_path']          = $path . '/' . $this->product_id;
$config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['file_name']            = $this->product_id;
$config['overwrite']            = true;
$config['max_size']             = 1024; // 1MB

if (!is_dir($path . $this->product_id)) {
    mkdir($path . $this->product_id, 0777, TRUE);
}

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if ($this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
    return $this->upload->data("file_name");
}

return "default.jpg";
}
```

Only the `_uploadImage` function worked, but the `_uploadImage2` not work

Can you tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have already initialize the upload library, so you have to re-initialize it.

Plus you should try to nest the functions, so they will be called in chain, or you don't want just use `$this->upload->initialize($config);` in the second function:

```php
private function _uploadImage($path)
{
    $config['upload_path']          = './upload/product/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['file_name']            = $this->product_id;
    $config['overwrite']            = true;
    $config['max_size']             = 1024; // 1MB
    // $config['max_width']            = 1024;
    // $config['max_height']           = 768;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ($this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
        return $this->_uploadImage2($path);
    }
    
    return "default.jpg";
}

private function _uploadImage2($path)
{
$config['upload_path']          = $path . '/' . $this->product_id;
$config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['file_name']            = $this->product_id;
$config['overwrite']            = true;
$config['max_size']             = 1024; // 1MB

if (!is_dir($path . $this->product_id)) {
    mkdir($path . $this->product_id, 0777, TRUE);
}

$this->upload->initialize($config);

if ($this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
    return $this->upload->data("file_name");
}

return "default.jpg";
}
```